# Asymptote in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, asymptote

Is there a way to directly embed Asymptote code in plain TeX as it can be done in LaTeX? (For example by using miniltx or something like that?)
Can labels in figures be typeset using plain TeX instead of LaTeX?
Something like what is discussed [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/2bbd2ca7/).

Comment: This requires reimplementing the `asymptote` package, basically.

Comment: @egreg: Well, go ahead -- it's a piece of cake for you, I assume ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I actually voted for “too broad”.

Comment: @egreg: Guess who voted too ;-)